# Alternatives to jGroups? Zookeeper?

Tags: java, clustering

Currently I am working on a distributed application which uses jGroups to ensure failover, high availability and performance.

```
-> Trigger existing nodes when a new node joins
-> Trigger other nodes when an existing node leaves
-> Make a RPC call from one node to another node in the cluster
```

I am just wondering if there are any other libraries available which offer the same features and which I could use as a total replacement to jGroups.

Does Zookeeper offer the same features and could be used instead of jGroups? I believe Akka does the same? Or is there any other library to consider?

Comment: Just a little hint: This site recommends software matching specific needs (which the larger part of your question is about). However, "where does Zookeeper fit" is just the opposite direction (recommending tasks a specific software fits), and thus is off-topic here. I've edited your question accordingly.